# Unable to copy objects on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to copy video files from in my store from one folder to another.  The files are all under 1GB. Everytime I try, I get an exception.

**Name of S3 store: BandMedia**

example files:

> SourceFileName: VideoFiles/Band1/video1_38372836.mp4
>
> DestinationFileName: VideoFiles/Band2/video1_47296110.mp4

The folder "VideoFiles" exist on my AWS S3 store.

However, the band name for the DestinationFileName is new(Band2).

So maybe it's not copying over because of that?  Would I need to create the folder for the band first, and then do the copy? But I'm pretty sure I read in the SDK documentation that if the folder doesn't exist, it will be automatically created.

Here's the code that copied pretty much from the AWS SDK examples:

```
  Try
        Dim AppSettings As Specialized.NameValueCollection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings()
        Dim AwsAccessKey As String = "xxxxxx"
        Dim AwsSecretKey As String = "11111"
        Dim AwsBucketName = "BandMedia"
        Dim AwsRegionEndpoint As String = AwsEndPoint

        Dim AwsRegionEndpointObj As RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(AwsRegionEndpoint)
        Dim s3 = New Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(AwsAccessKey, AwsSecretKey, AwsRegionEndpointObj)

        Dim cRequest As CopyObjectRequest
        Dim cReponse As CopyObjectResponse

        cRequest = New CopyObjectRequest()

        With cRequest
            .SourceBucket = AwsBucketName
            .DestinationBucket = AwsBucketName
            .SourceKey = SourceFileName
            .DestinationKey = DestinationFileName
            .CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
        End With

        cReponse = s3.CopyObject(cRequest) 
        Return cReponse.HttpStatusCode = 200
    Catch ex As AmazonS3Exception 
        Return False
    End Try
```

Here's the error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in videoMusicApp.dll Exception
> while copying file VideoFiles/Band1/video1_38372836.mp4 to
> VideoFiles/Band2/video1_47296110.mp4

Another thought...maybe it's because it's on the same store?

Honestly, I don't know though.

Could anyone help me out?  Thanks!

Comment: If there's a problem with the request to S3, you should be hitting your `catch` for `AmazonS3Exception`. Are you? If not, something else is up. What is the message in the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Did you particularly want to do this via your own code? If not, then the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a useful `aws s3 cp` command that you could use.